# Redirect IE9 and IE8 visitors to different home page in same website

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9, redirect

On my Wordpress site, Homepage has some JavaScripts and links that are not working on IE9. The theme developer saying that IE9 is not compatible and not taking the responsibility.

Now, I have created another page with the same exact look but no Javascript on that. I want to redirect IE9 user to that page when they open the site.

I tried different codes in header.php one of the code is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('MSIE') !=-1){
    window.location = "http://newpage.com"
  }
</script>
```

Problem is, this code redirect all website links to the redirected link but I only want to redirect the home page.

I will really appreciate if someone can help.

Thank you.

Comment: You can do this server-side too. It would be way better in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks for the Suggestion Phiter, could you please provide any link for the guidance? thanks

Answer (score 0):

As per Phiter's comment, this is something that can and probably should be done on the server side with a redirect, but if you *really* want to do it on the client side, simply expand your test case to compare the current window location:

```
if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('MSIE') !=-1 
    && window.location === "http://homepage.com"){
  window.location = "http://newpage.com"
}
```

This could be done with an exact match like above, or a regular expression.

Comment: && window.location === "http://myhomepage.com") this command is not working. when I remove this redirection works (but that is for all website links, not for a specific page).

Comment: Use the debugger to print out what the actual window location is on the homepage, and use that value.